# How can I override the browser-generated triangle icon in a <details> element?

Tags: html, icons, html-tag-details

I'd like to change the icon with CSS for this snippet of HTML5:

```
<details>
  <summary>Hello</summary>
  <p>The details</p>
</details>
```

Any clues?

Comment: What browser are you using? On my Firefox 6 I don't see an icon

Answer (score 2):

On WebKit browsers you could do:

```
summary::-webkit-details-marker {display: none}

summary:before {content: ""}
details[open] summary:before {content: ""}
```

Comment: [Seems like](http://jsfiddle.net/m47yd/1/) only the first line is necessary, at least in Chrome 16. That's the only browser I see the generated content in, however. I've never even heard of this element until just now though, so future browsers might need the rest :) EDIT: Oh right, to override the icon you need the psuedo element.